# Some relations between signed distance function, closest point mapping, and tangential projection of an embedded surface?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, surfaces

I read a [paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/140982696) who states:

> Consider an embedded orientable surface $\Sigma \subset \mathbf{R}^3$
>   and $\Sigma \in C^2$ with exterior unit normal $n$. Let $\rho$ be the
>   signed distance function such that $\nabla \rho = n$ on $\Sigma$ and
>   let $p(x) = x - \rho(x) n(p(x))$ be the closest point mapping. ...The
>   tangential gradient $\nabla_\Sigma$ is defined by $\nabla_\Sigma=P_\Sigma \nabla$, where $\nabla$ is the $\mathbf{R}^3$ gradient and
>   $P_\Sigma(x) = I - n(x) \otimes n(x)$ is the projection onto the
>   tangent plane $T_\Sigma(x)$ of $\Sigma$ at $x$.

Later it gives an identity without proof:

> ...Then we use the identity $Dp = P_\Sigma - \rho \mathcal{H}$,
>   where $\mathcal{H}$ is the Hessian of the distance function
>   $\mathcal{H} = \nabla \otimes \nabla \rho$.

**Why does this identity hold true? I cannot derive it from the previous settings.**

And later without proof it says:

> ...Then we use the fact that $P_\Sigma - \rho \mathcal{H} = (P_\Sigma-\rho \mathcal{H})P_\Sigma$.

**But I cannot understand the fact as well.**

As for the paper, you may find it via the following two links:

http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/140982696

https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.3043 (free)

Comment: Can you also link the paper?

Comment: Yes, I've attached the links. Thanks for reviewing.

Comment: Thanks, can you also link which page numbers? There are lots of similar equations in the paper.

Comment: The first statements can be found at section 2.1 in page 1807 (or 2), and section 3.1 in page 1808 (or 4). The equations questioned can be found in section 4.1 in page 1810 (or 6), under the Eq (4.3) and Eq (4.6).

Comment: Looks to me like they actually claim $P_\Sigma - \rho \mathcal H = P_\Sigma (P_\Sigma - \rho \mathcal H)$. Once you know this is just $Dp = P_\Sigma Dp$, it is obvious: the image of $Dp(x)$ lies in the tangent space $T_{p(x)} \Sigma$, and $P_\Sigma|_{T \Sigma}$ is the identity. To establish $Dp= P_\Sigma - \rho \mathcal H$, I think you just need to differentiate the implicit equation $p(x) = x - \rho(x) n(p(x))$ and do some linear algebra to solve for $Dp$.